# Swift 4 Programming for filtering large array with specific condition

Tags: swift

kindly note that my question is specific to **Swift 4** syntax. I have a **bulky/large** **array of Strings** and I want to filter it for getting all values in it which are started with some specific **characters/substring**. That means I need each String in my array which matches to started with some substring. I found different links which gives me code for **Objective-C** and I am unable to implement it in **Swift 4** because of that methods are not available in **Swift 4**. I solved my question manually by iterating my array in for loop but it gives very slow result So I don't want to use any loop here, So any help will useful. Thanks in advance. See my code below:

```
func search() -> Void {
        var dummyStringsArray:[String] = ["Hotel Restaurants","Restaurants","Certified Green Restaurant(R)","Japnies Food Restauarants","Grill Restaurants","Restaurant Equipment","Wholsale Restaurant Fixtures","American Food","Wholsale Restaurant Supplies","Veg Restaurants","Barbecue Restaurants","Non-Veg Restaurants"]
        var displayDataArray:[String] = []
        let searchString:NSString = (textField.text!).lowercased() as NSString
        for string in self.dummyStringsArray {
            let mainString:NSString = string.lowercased() as NSString
            if mainString.length >= searchString.length {
                let compareString = String(mainString.substring(to: searchString.length))
                if searchString as String == compareString {
                    displayDataArray.append(string)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So if I entered text in textField as '**re**' then it should return displayDataArray containing values like "Restaurants", "Restaurant Equipment".

Comment: `filter` might help?

Comment: Use NSPredicate

Comment: How NSPredicate will be used with filter method in Swift 4? Actually I need a piece of code which will clearly understood how to use it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this without any loop because you need to go through all the elements

But I can offer you more elegant solution with `filter` function:

```
func search() -> Void {
    let dummyStringsArray:[String] = ["Hotel Restaurants","Restaurants","Certified Green Restaurant(R)","Japnies Food Restauarants","Grill Restaurants","Restaurant Equipment","Wholsale Restaurant Fixtures","American Food","Wholsale Restaurant Supplies","Veg Restaurants","Barbecue Restaurants","Non-Veg Restaurants"]
    let searchString: String = (textField.text!).lowercased()
    let displayDataArray: [String] = dummyStringsArray.filter({ String($0.prefix(searchString.count)).lowercased() == searchString })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get the best performance using `range(of:options:)` while passing in the options of `.caseInsensitive` and `.anchored`.

```
func search() -> Void {
    let dummyStringsArray = ["Hotel Restaurants","Restaurants","Certified Green Restaurant(R)","Japnies Food Restauarants","Grill Restaurants","Restaurant Equipment","Wholsale Restaurant Fixtures","American Food","Wholsale Restaurant Supplies","Veg Restaurants","Barbecue Restaurants","Non-Veg Restaurants"]
    let searchString = textField.text!
    let displayDataArray = dummyStringsArray.filter { $0.range(of: searchString, options: [ .caseInsensitive, .anchored ]) != nil }
}
```